# Loading image from url in side navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-side-navigation

I'm trying to achieve a Google+ like side navigation drawer with profile pic loaded from the facebook id.

All's well except the image doesn't load inside the side navigation drawer. I've tried Picasso as well Volley image loader + NetworkImageView but doesn't seem to help. All it shows is the placeholder image.

My doubts : Is it possible to load dynamic image inside side navigation drawer ? If yes, is it similar to the normal image loading from url ?

Thanks.